# Many to Many doctrine symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have a problem. My problem is this.

Have a tables: product, categories, products_categories

```
    Product
+----+--------------------------+
| id | title                    |
+----+--------------------------+
|  1 | Product 1                |
|  2 | Product 2                |
+----+--------------------------+

    Categries
+----+----------------------+----------+
| id | title                | slug     |
+----+----------------------+----------+
|  1 | Categories 1         | cat1     |
|  2 | Categories 2         | cat2     |
|  3 | Categories 3         | cat3     |
+----+----------------------+----------+

    Produts_Categories
+----------+---------------+
| product_id | category_id |
+----------+---------------+
|        1 |        3      |
|        2 |        3      |
|        1 |        1      |
+----------+---------------+
```

I need to do this:

1. Get products from category id
2. Get all products with category

My Product Entity

```php
namespace ProductBundle\Entity;

use AppBundle\AppBundle;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Entity\Categories;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ProductBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection $categories
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Categories")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_categories",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $categories;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
 */
private $userId;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $slug;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
 */
private $updatedAt;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set userId
 *
 * @param integer $userId
 * @return Product
 */
public function setUserId($userId)
{
    $this->userId = $userId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get userId
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getUserId()
{
    return $this->userId;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 * @return Product
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 * @return Product
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set slug
 *
 * @param string $slug
 * @return Product
 */
public function setSlug($slug)
{
    $this->slug = $slug;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get slug
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSlug()
{
    return $this->slug;
}

/**
 * Set createdAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $createdAt
 * @return Product
 */
public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
{
    $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get createdAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

/**
 * Set updatedAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
 * @return Product
 */
public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
{
    $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updatedAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getUpdatedAt()
{
    return $this->updatedAt;
}

/**
 * @return User
 *
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

/**
 * @param User $user
 */
public function setUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Add categories
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Categories $categories
 * @return Product
 */
public function addCategory(\AppBundle\Entity\Categories $categories)
{
    $this->categories[] = $categories;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove categories
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Categories $categories
 */
public function removeCategory(\AppBundle\Entity\Categories $categories)
{
    $this->categories->removeElement($categories);
}

/**
 * Get categories
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getCategories()
{
    return $this->categories;
}
}
```

My Categories Entity

```php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Categories
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="categories")
 *    @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CategoriesRepository")
 */
class Categories
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="parent", type="integer")
 */
private $parent;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="pos", type="integer")
 */
private $pos;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $slug;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set parent
 *
 * @param integer $parent
 * @return Categories
 */
public function setParent($parent)
{
    $this->parent = $parent;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get parent
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return $this->parent;
}

/**
 * Set pos
 *
 * @param integer $pos
 * @return Categories
 */
public function setPos($pos)
{
    $this->pos = $pos;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get parent
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getPos()
{
    return $this->pos;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 * @return Categories
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set slug
 *
 * @param string $slug
 * @return Categories
 */
public function setSlug($slug)
{
    $this->slug = $slug;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get slug
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSlug()
{
    return $this->slug;
}
}
```

ProductController

```php
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$repository = $em->getRepository('ProductBundle:Product');
$products = $repository
->findAll();
```

But it doesnt work. I get this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Product {#675 ▼
    -id: 1
    -categories: PersistentCollection {#676 ▼
      -snapshot: []
      -owner: Product {#675}
      -association: array:19 [ …19]
      -em: EntityManager {#574 …10}
      -backRefFieldName: null
      -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#583 …}
      -isDirty: false
      -initialized: false
      -coll: ArrayCollection {#677 ▶}
    }
    -userId: 1
    -user: User {#696 ▶}
    -title: "hjhkhk"
    -description: "hjhkjhkjh"
    -slug: "hjhkjhkj"
    -createdAt: DateTime {#672 ▶}
    -updatedAt: DateTime {#673 ▶}
  }
  1 => Product {#693 ▶}
]
```

Comment: And? What do You expect to get? "Get all products with category" doesn't say much. Your products seem to have some category.

Comment: I want to get the products by category id. And, the product array to have information about the categories associated with the product (name, id and etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st approach:**

```
public function findProductsByCategory($categoryId) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $qb->select('p, cat')
        ->leftJoin('p.categories', 'cat')
        ->where('cat.id = :catId')
        ->setParameter('catId', $categoryId);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

This query will return products for given category. If you want to receive categories for each product, you will have to iterate through products and get categories for each one.

**2nd approach:**

```
public function getProductsWithCategories() {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $qb->select('p, cat')
        ->leftJoin('p.categories', 'cat');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

This query will return all products with joined categories. Now You have to filter out in code those products, which you are interested in.

**The difference:**

In 1st approach You will send a query when asking for category for each product.

In 2nd approach the code is responsible for filtering products. So basically it depends whether you want to DB or code to handle more load.

Comment: In this function findProductsByCategory() I get info about one category, which I have chosen. But this product has 2 diferent categories. How fix it?

Comment: be specific. What does it mean that you get info about one category.

Answer (score 0):

You might to do your own request in the repository with your own logics (as it seems quite unclear what you want exactly), such as:

```
public function findProducts() {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $qb ->leftJoin('p.categories', 'cat');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```